# How do I run a function cordova if the command embedded in external sites?

Tags: javascript, cordova-3, cordova-plugins, inappbrowser

I want to run a function to open the link in the android browser system. Here is an illustration of my questions. [See the illustration](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-XUZ_PYkyxeg/VKOr36REG2I/AAAAAAAAAzw/E72i7MgHdU0/s1600/inappbrowser-open-system.jpg) What should I do?  I only use javascript not java. Please help

Answer (score 0):

Some time ago I encountered the same problem. To do this I modified the InAppBrowser source code.
you should override the shouldOverrideUrlLoading method in the InAppBrowserClient class found in InAppBrowser.java

This will allow you to hook in to the request before the url is being loaded and choose an alternate behavior. In your case loading the URL in the system browser.

Your code will look something like this:

```
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading (WebView view, String url){
    if(url.equals("Your URL to be loaded")){
        openExternal(url);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Hi Michael Thank you for reply, but I don't use java. I do not use Eclipse or any other Java software. I'm just using Html5, CSS, Javascript with PhoneGap Build and also Cordova Build by intel XDK. I just want to how to be able to run the command cordova on external site not on lokal. Only use javascript, roughly there a solution? What javascript code that I have to edit or add on external site and lokal assets?

Comment: I have looked for a javascript solution myself and did not find one. The problem is that the plugin does not provide any means of hooking in before a request starts. Anyway, it is a Cordova based solution so you should have the source code of the plugin available somewhere I guess. If it's a phonegap build based plugin then there is no way to change it as the plugin source code is only available in the build cloud. I don't know how the intel XDK works as I have never used it. Sorry if this doesn't answer your question but in my experience this is the only solution available for this problem.